# OSX Yosemite and RVM broken SSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, rvm, osx-yosemite

My OS is OS X Yosemite (10.10.5) and I have installed RVM for managing ruby versions and gemsets. I am using different gemsets and I have problems with SSL randomly (most often when I restart and change gemset). So for example this is the kind of error I am getting when I am doing `bundle`:

> Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
>
> Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4):
>   Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL
>   certificate for https://rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are
>   experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system
>   doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
>   information about OpenSSL certificates, see http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To
>   connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change
>   'https' to 'http'. Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4):
>   Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL
>   certificate for https://rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are
>   experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system
>   doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
>   information about OpenSSL certificates, see http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To
>   connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change
>   'https' to 'http'. Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4):
>   Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL
>   certificate for https://rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are
>   experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system
>   doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
>   information about OpenSSL certificates, see http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To
>   connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change
>   'https' to 'http'.Could not verify the SSL certificate for
>   https://rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are experiencing a
>   man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the
>   CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL
>   certificates, see http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html. To connect without using
>   SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.

I tried many times the recommendations from the RVM site ([fixing-broken-certificates](https://rvm.io/support/fixing-broken-ssl-certificates)) without any luck, it seems like the only way to fix it temporary is this command:

`curl https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o "$(ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE')"` (downloads and places the specific cert).

But after a while (restart and ruby / gemset change), it fails again. Any idea? Anyone else has a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still having this problem, give the following solution a try:

`rvm install 2.3.0 --disable-binary`

I also had some success pointing the `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable to a local version of `cacert.pem`. You can try it out if reinstalling the Rubies using the above solution doesn't work.

Comment: I updated to sierra and the problem went away so I can't try your solution, but thank you very much for your suggestion.